# Create CSS selector for nested element with more than one attribute

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm trying to select a checkbox that's nested in a div of a page, for acceptance testing purposes.

Here's an example of the DOM structure I might see:

```
...
<div class="section-1">
    ...
    <input type="checkbox" name="type[12312][][]" value="1">Thing1</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="type[12312][][]" value="2">Thing2</input>
    ...
</div>
...
```

Normally, I could do something like this to select a particular checkbox:

```
input[name*=type][value=1]
```

But in my case, I need the checkbox in a particular section, of which there are many in the page. So I assumed the following would work:

```
.section-1 input[name*=type][value=1]
```

but it does *not*.

My questions are:

1. Why doesn't it work?
2. How can I select the input now?

**Note:** I could use JS to get the input, but I would *really* prefer to use CSS selectors so I can use the library(Selenium)'s functions to handle element manipulation.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your css selector except missing `'`. It works for me in this way `.section-1 input[name*='type'][value='1']`

Comment: This works too `.section-1>input[name*='type'][value='1']`

Comment: Your "summary" is actually an answer. Please move it into the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```css
.section-1 input[name^="type"][value="2"] {
    display: block;
    margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="type[12312][][]" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="type[12312][][]" value="2">
</div>
```

Try adding quotation marks to your attribute values.

Also, the `input` element is a [**void element**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements). It does not have a closing tag and does not accept content.

Comment: Your answer is very thorough, so I will vote it best answer! The quotes were the issue, as I didn't realize that adding quotes around attribute values made a difference. It didn't make a difference for the first attribute, after all. Thanks for pointing out that input elements are void, that's my mistake as well. I believe I copied it down wrong.

Answer (score 1):

u have to use > if you want to go to child.
use the below cssSelector for selenium element locator:

```
.section-1 > input[name^= 'type'][value= '1']
```

i use ^ as ur name starts with type.

hope this will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately > is only for immediate children, and this is not an immediate child. I'll try your suggest though

Comment: The quotes worked! Wow. I thought quotes were optional around the values of attributes, but apparently that was my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: yes > this for immediate but u also give some attribute to check which immediate children will be selected. as u use value = 1 , it will select that immediate child which value is 1

Answer (score 0):

It was the missing quotes around the values of the attributes that caused this to fail. According to the spec, attribute values can either be identifiers or strings. I see now that an identifier can contain letters and numbers, but must *not* begin with a number. This is why it failed.